# Candy Machine Java

Tags: java, jgrasp

Please help solve the following code I got stuck (i'm new to java)
the homework said I need to build a computer candy machine in code.
here is the output of the homework:

```
Welcome to Shoreline's Computer Candy Machine!
(All candy provided is virtual.)

How much money do you have? > $1.00
$1.00, that's all?

Well, let me tell you what we got here.
A $0.65 Twix
B $0.50 Chips
C $0.75 Nutter Butter
D $0.65 Peanut Butter Cup
E $0.55 Juicy Fruit Gum

So, What do you want? > C

Thanks for purchasing candy through us.
Please take your candy and your $0.25 change!
```

or:

```
Welcome to Shoreline's Computer Candy Machine!
(All candy provided is virtual.)

How much money do you have? > .50
$0.50, that's all?

Well, let me tell you what we got here.
A $0.65 Twix
B $0.50 Chips
C $0.75 Nutter Butter
D $0.65 Peanut Butter Cup
E $0.55 Juicy Fruit Gum

So, What do you want? > D

You are short $0.15, you are unable to purchase your snack
```

here is my code(i haven't finished it):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CandyMachine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        verse1();
      System.out.println();
        verse2();
        System.out.println();
      verse3();
      System.out.println();
      verse4();
    }

   public static void verse1() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Shoreline's Computer Candy Machine!");
       System.out.println("(All candy provided is virtual.)");
   }
   public static void verse2() {
   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("How much money do you have? >"); //prompts for a whole number
   double money = console.nextDouble();
   System.out.printf("%.2f, that's all?", money);
   }
   public static void verse3() {
   System.out.println("Well, let me tell you what we got here.");
   System.out.println("A $0.65 Twix");
   System.out.println("B $0.50 Chips");
   System.out.println("C $0.75 Nutter Butter");
   System.out.println("D $0.65 Peanut Butter Cup");
   System.out.println("E $0.55 Juicy Fruit Gum");
   }
   public static void verse4() {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("So, What do you want? >"); //prompts for a whole number
   String a = input.next();
   if (a.equals("A"))
      if (money > 0.65)
         System.out.println("Thanks for purchasing candy through us."); 
   else
   }
   }
```

I got stuck in `verse4()`. I mean am I doing it right? How can I take "money" in `verse2()` and use it in `verse4()` or what should I do? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the variable `money` in verse2 is outside the scope of verse4.
If you define a variable inside a method, it only exists in that method. It should work if you write:

```
double money;
```

right under the opening bracket of your class, then change

```
double money = console.nextDouble();
```

in verse2 to:

```
money = console.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `money` variable as a global variable so it would be accessed anywhere. Also it needs to be `static` since your methods are all static. I did start your `verse4()` method, the only thing to consider is that if the user doesn't have enough money... what would happen? This is why the `else{...}` is commented for homework ;)! Also, you must know the difference between `>=` and `>`. They are crucial in your program. Good luck.

```
static double money;//must be a global variable so it could be accessed from all methods.
    //you declared it in verse2() method what means that you can ONLY access it in verse2().

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        verse1();
        System.out.println();
        verse2();
        System.out.println();
        verse3();
        System.out.println();
        verse4();
    }

    public static void verse1() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Shoreline's Computer Candy Machine!");
        System.out.println("(All candy provided is virtual.)");
    }

    public static void verse2() {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How much money do you have? >"); //prompts for a whole number
        money = console.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("%.2f, that's all?", money);
    }

    public static void verse3() {
        System.out.println("Well, let me tell you what we got here.");
        System.out.println("A $0.65 Twix");
        System.out.println("B $0.50 Chips");
        System.out.println("C $0.75 Nutter Butter");
        System.out.println("D $0.65 Peanut Butter Cup");
        System.out.println("E $0.55 Juicy Fruit Gum");
    }

    public static void verse4() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("So, What do you want? >"); //prompts for a whole number
        String a = input.next();
        double change = 0;//the amount of change to give back.
        //check which candy they picked as well as if the money is equal or larger than the price.
        //not the >= is very important, you only had >.
        if (a.equals("A") && money >= 0.65) {
            change = money - 0.65;//calculate the change by doing the money - price of candy.
            System.out.println("Thanks for purchasing candy through us.");
            System.out.println("Please take your candy and your $" + change + " change!");
        } else if (a.equals("B") && money >= 0.50) {//same thing for item B, and check the price
            change = money - 0.50;
            System.out.println("Thanks for purchasing candy through us.");
            System.out.println("Please take your candy and your $" + change + " change!");
        }//now do items C,D,E in with the same logic.
        //now you need to make sure that maybe the user doesn't have enough money...
        //you would you the else{...} to prompt to user that the money is not enough.
    }
```